# Algorithm for finding mutual name in lists

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've been reading up on Algorithms from the book Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick and I've  been stuck on an exercise problem for a while. Here is the question :

Given 3 lists of `N` names each, find an algorithm to determine if there is any name common to all three lists. The algorithm must have O(Nlog<sup>N</sup>) complexity. You're only allowed to use sorting algorithms and the only data structures you can use are stacks and queues.

I figured I could solve this problem using a HashMap, but the questions restricts us from doing so. Even then that still wouldn't have a complexity of Nlog<sup>N</sup>.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: how would combining them help ?

Comment: @CraigTreptow - This is a programming question so why would it not be allowed here ?

Comment: If you combined the lists, sorted it, and looked for 3 sequential names (assuming each list can only have a name at most 1 time).

Comment: @Nick Chris - well my thought was that it is an algorithm question as mentioned in the FAQ for programmers

Comment: Because they are lists and not sets, I would think you can't assume that a list can only have a name one time.

Comment: We cant assume that each list has distinct names

Answer (score 3):

If you sort each of the lists, then you could trivially check if all three lists have any 1 name in O(n) time by picking the first name of list A compare it to the first name in list B, if that element is < that of list A, pop the list b element and repeat until list B >= list A.  If you find a match repeat the process on C.  If you find a match in C also return true, otherwise return to the next element in a.

Now you have to sort all of the lists in n log n time.  which you could do with your favorite sorting algorithm though you would have to be a little creative using just stacks and queues.  I would probably recommend merge sort

The below psuedo code is a little messed up because I am changing lists that I am iterating over

pseudo code:
assume listA, b and c are sorted Queues where the smallest name is at the top of the queue.

```
eltB = listB.pop()
eltC = listC.pop()
for eltA in listA:
    while(eltB<=eltA):
        if eltB==eltA:                
            while(eltC<=eltB):
                if eltB==eltC:
                    return true
                if eltC<eltB:
                    eltC=listC.pop();
        eltB=listB.pop()
```

Comment: IMHO, the first paragraph provides a complete answer. The rest just obfuscates it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Sort the three lists using an `O(N lgN)` sorting algorithm.
2. Pop the one item from each list.
3. If any of the lists from which you tried to pop is empty, then you are done i.e. no common element exists.
4. Else, compare the three elements.
5. If the elements are equal, you are done - you have found the common element.
6. Else, keep the maximum of the three elements (constant time) and replenish from the *same lists* from which the two elements were discarded.
7. Go to step 3.

Step 1 takes `O(N lgN)` and the rest of the steps take `O(N)`, so the overall complexity is `O(N lgN)`.